# JPQL: Access to outer attributes in JOIN of subquery

Tags: jpa, jpql

In my JPA model there are 3 tables A, B, C.

My query is:

```
SELECT a FROM A a
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT c from C c LEFT JOIN B b"
    ON c = b.c AND b.a = a
    WHERE c.date BETWEEN CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AND :pUntil AND b.a IS NULL
)
```

Background is that I want all entities of A that do not have an entry in b that is linked to an event C in the future.

The problem is that I get `Column 'T0.ID' is either not in any table in the FROM list or appears within a join specification and is outside the scope of the join specification or ...`

**EDIT**
: Think of it as A is a user table, C are events, and B stores the registrations of users for events. I want to get all users, which have not registered for all future events until parameter `pUntil`.

Comment: no reason why they should not be referenceable IMHO, raise a bug on your provider.

Comment: Thanks. I agree that this should work. 'a' is referenceable in the WHERE condition but not in the ON condition. This is weird behavior. If you know how to work around this limitation, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I agree with Neil, I worked around this issue by changing my query. Here's the new query:

```
SELECT a FROM A a
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT c from C c
    WHERE c.date BETWEEN CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AND :pUntil
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT b from B b
        WHERE b.c= c and b.a = a
    )
)
```